# Using Count value in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to use the result of COUNT to limit the results. For example, I only want to show rows where the count (matching_img_count) is greater than / equal to 2.

```
SELECT tel_number.number, COUNT(DISTINCT(i2.id_img)) as matching_img_count
    FROM img_reference i
        JOIN img_reference i2 ON i.id_img = i2.id_img
            AND i2.id_tel=13777
        JOIN tel_number ON i.id_tel = tel_number.id_tel
WHERE tel_number.id_tel != 13777
GROUP BY i.id_tel, i2.id_tel
```

I've tried two things:

```
HAVING matching_img_count >= 2
```

and

```
WHERE matching_img_count >= 2
```

No luck... Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A query *cannot* refer to an *output* identifier in the WHERE clause or anywhere else inside the query - which is used to generate the output values! If you ever need such behavior you'll have to use a nested query. However, `GROUP BY .. HAVING` does what you need here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `HAVING` to filter based on values in the `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT tel_number.number, COUNT(DISTINCT(i2.id_img)) as matching_img_count
FROM img_reference i
JOIN img_reference i2 ON i.id_img = i2.id_img
JOIN tel_number ON i.id_tel = tel_number.id_tel
WHERE tel_number.id_tel != 13777
    AND i2.id_tel=13777
GROUP BY i.id_tel, i2.id_tel
HAVING matching_img_count > 1
```

Also, when performing an `INNER JOIN`, the `ON` clause should only have conditions that relate two tables. All single-table conditions should be in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Ah. Thank you! I think I just made a syntax error. I placed HAVING following the WHERE clause which was throwing any error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT tel_number.number, COUNT(DISTINCT(i2.id_img)) as matching_img_count
    FROM img_reference i
        JOIN img_reference i2
             ON i.id_img = i2.id_img
        JOIN tel_number
             ON i.id_tel = tel_number.id_tel
WHERE tel_number.id_tel != 13777
       AND i2.id_tel=13777
GROUP BY i.id_tel, i2.id_tel
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(i2.id_img)) >= 2
```